# MySQL Stored Procedure ignora ELSE dentro de un IF Statement

Tags: c#, mysql, login, stored-procedure

buen dia, estoy creando un sistema de login en C# usando un stored procedure.

```
    IF CONTEO = 1 THEN 
SELECT US.CUSU_CUSUARIO AS USUARIO , USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL AS ROL
#INTO USUARIO, ROL 
FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS US
INNER JOIN INHA_DET_CFGUSUROL USUROL ON USUROL.CUSR_NIDUSUARIO = US.CUSU_NIDUSUARIO
INNER JOIN INHA_MST_CFGROLES ROLS ON ROLS.CFRO_NIDROL = USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL  WHERE US.CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA AND US.CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1; 
SET PRESULTADO = 'OK';
ELSE
SET PRESULTADO = 'CONTRASEÑA';
END IF;
```

El problema es que, cuando el usuario ingresa la contraseña correcta, si deja iniciar sesion, tomando el PRESULTADO de OK, pero al momento de introducir mal la contraseña, de alguna u otra manera, en vez de darme el resultado de PRESULTADO Contraseña, me termina dando un Data Entry Null 0

¿A que se deberia dicho problema?

Comment: Puede que sea un problema debido a la `Ñ`, intenta poner otra cosa sin `Ñ`, ni acentos ni caracteres especiales. Si vas a trabajar con ese tipo de datos tienes que configurar bien la codificación.

Comment: De donde sale la variable CONTEO ? Que es lo que intentas hacer con `#INTO USUARIO, ROL ` ? tampoco veo que apliques ningun EXISTS para validar si la query retorno algun registro y devolver un valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podria ser algo como esto

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
             FROM INHA_DET_CFGUSUARIOS US
             INNER JOIN INHA_DET_CFGUSUROL USUROL ON USUROL.CUSR_NIDUSUARIO = US.CUSU_NIDUSUARIO
             INNER JOIN INHA_MST_CFGROLES ROLS ON ROLS.CFRO_NIDROL = USUROL.CUSR_NIDROL  
             WHERE US.CUSU_CUSUARIO = PUSU AND US.CUSU_CCONTRASENIA = PCONTRA AND US.CUSU_NESTATUSUSUARIO  = 1) THEN 
    SET PRESULTADO = 'OK';
ELSE
    SET PRESULTADO = 'CONTRASEÑA';
END IF;
```

habria que ver si el exists se puede asignar a una variable y evaluarla, pero igual creo se entiende la idea

[Select IF EXISTS THEN ELSE on Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627825/select-if-exists-then-else-on-mysql)